# How upload file in remote machine (LAN) using Flajaxian FileUploader

Tags: asp.net

really it's a crucial point for me, my quastion is :

How upload file in remote machine (LAN) using Flajaxian FileUploader.

Env : C# , ASP.NET , VS .NET 2005

please help

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Read help here: http://flajaxian.com/flajaxian.com/FileUploader2.0Help.html

Comment: the help, does not contain how to upload to remote machine or ipaddress.

Comment: BMTU: I think all you need to know is in that online help. The Flajaxian FileUploader helps you to transport a file from client side to server side, then you use a custom adapter and save the file wherever you wish.

Comment: Al Keep: Thanks for reply, the help url you post really does not contain more details, but the forum http://flajaxianfileupload.codeplex.com/discussions?ProjectName=flajaxianfileupload , you can find more details you want.